# How do I code the php file to connect my multi-step form to MySQL database?

Tags: php, silverstripe

```
<?php
class JpResearchSurveyDbPage extends DataObject{
static $db = array(
'year_living' => 'Varchar(200)',
'other_public_transport' => 'Varchar(50)',
'year_living1' => 'Varchar(200)',
'type_of_mode_unfamiliar_services' => 'Varchar(50)'
);
enter code here
}
$host="localhost"; 
$username="sgevh_admin"; 
$password="q1w2e3r4t5";  
$db_name="sgevh_test";
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO year (aaa,bbb,ccc,eee)
VALUES
('$_POST[year_living]','$_POST[other_public_transport]','$_POST[type_of_mode_unfamiliar_services]','$_POST[year_living1]')";

    //$sql="INSERT INTO month (ccc)
    //VALUES
    //('$_POST[type_of_mode_unfamiliar_services]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
?>`
```

//This is the test php coding that we used to connect our multi-step form to our database.

```
<?php
class JpResearchSurveyMultiForm extends MultiForm{
public static $start_step = 'JpResearchSurveyFirstStep';
public function finish($data, $form){
parent::finish($data, $form);
$firstStep = $this->getSavedStepByClass('JpResearchSurveyFirstStep');
$_JpResearchSurveyFirstPage = new JpResearchSurveyDbPage();
$firstStep->saveInto($_JpResearchSurveyFirstPage);

$secondStep = $this->getSavedStepByClass('JpResearchSurveySecondStep');
$secondStep->saveInto($_JpResearchSurveyFirstPage);

$_JpResearchSurveyFirstPage->write();
return $this->controller->customise(array(
'Form' => false,
'Content' => 'Thanks for registering!'
))->renderWith('Page');
}
}
?>
```

//This is the test coding which gives instruction as to what will the final step of the form do when we press the "submit" button to submit the data. When we tried out the form and submit the details using our two pages form, only the fields' data of the second page which is the final step of the form was stored in the database.

Which of the two coding is giving us the problem of not being able to store the fields' data in the previous forms sessions?

Comment: You need to do some trouble shooting on your own and narrow down the problem. Once you pinpoint the trouble spot, post the section of code that is causing the problem

Comment: i dont see any attempt to save anything in the session ... nor do i see a session_start() call at all

Answer (score 0):

It's not preferable to save each step in the database and update on each step. Instead use session and cookie to manage user input, and on the final step, store them on the DB. Just keep in mind to kill the session afterward